# SQLAlchemy dynamic construction of GENERATED column

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, generated-columns

I want to dynamically derive columns with the `server_default` set to [`Computed(...)`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Computed).

The statement going into `Computed(...)` has to be derived from other columns, and therefore needs to have access to the class *after* the [`relationship`s](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship) have been mapped:

```py
from uuid import uuid4
from sqlalchemy import func, Computed, ForeignKey, Column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql.base import Executable
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import INTEGER, UUID

def aggregate_computed(relationship: str, column: Column, expr: Executable):
    ...

@as_declarative()
class Base: pass

class Other(Base):
    __tablename__ = "other"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    this = relationship("This", back_populates="other")
    this_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("this.id"))

class This(Base, IDMixin):
    __tablename__ = "this"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    other = relationship("Other", back_populates="this")
    other_count = aggregate_computed("species", Column(INTEGER), func.count(1))

assert isinstance(This.other_count.server_default, Computed)
assert This.other_count.server_default.sqltext == """\
SELECT count(1) AS out
FROM other
WHERE this.id = other.this_id
"""
```

Where the query is constructed as such:

```sql
-- this is the decorated function
SELECT count(1) AS out
-- this is derived from the relationships.
-- for a m-to-n relation, it would make use of the `secondary` table
FROM other WHERE this.id = other.this_id
```

I know how to construct the query from the relationships, but I don’t know how to tell SQLAlchemy how to map everything except for my properties, then finish mapping while allowing those properties access to the class’s relationships.

The answer here is NOT:

- “Simply use a `column_property`”: Those accept only finished columns, and don’t allow to construct them with access to the mapped class
- “Use `sqlalchemy_utils.aggregate`”: That one is implemented via `after_flush` trigger, not `GENERATED ALWAYS AS`.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed relatively easily possible, by creating a subclass of `Computed` that can be passed to the column. That subclass defines `sqltext` as a property instead of a instance variable. Since that property is only accessed after mapping, it has access to the fully mapped model class.

Unfortunately what I actually wanted to do with it is impossible, as the generated statement is not valid in PostgreSQL (`GENERATED ALWAYS AS` cannot use nested queries).

Nevertheless the approach might be useful for other dynamically generated `GENERATED ALWAYS AS` statements.

```py
class ComputedAggregate(Computed):
    def __init__(self, relationship: str, expr, *, persisted=None):
        # do not call super().__init__, as it tries to set self.sqltext
        self.relationship = relationship
        self.expr = expr
        self.persisted = persisted
        self.column = None

    @property
    def sqltext(self):
        cls = get_class_by_table(MyBase, self.column.table)
        relationships: t.List[RelationshipProperty] = list(
            reversed(path_to_relationships(self.relationship, cls))
        )
        query = select_correlated_expression(
            cls,
            self.expr,
            self.relationship,
            relationships[0].mapper.class_,
        )
        return query.as_scalar()
```